# Need real time example of an action in Microsoft dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015

In Microsoft Dynamics CRM, I know the requirements when to use the plugin, workflows and custom workflows, but I cannot come across those cases or situations when I can use the actions or custom actions.
Can anybody suggest me real time requirement when to  use the action?

If possible, please demonstrate an "action" with an example.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple use is when you need to execute some server side code from JavaScript by clicking a button in the ribbon OR any where in the client side(not on an entity delete, update, create etc.... messages.) , then you need to create an Action.

e.g if you have to implement some logic and you feel it would be very complex Or not possible on client side (JavaScript), then you should just create an action, implement your logic in that action(server side) and call that action in JavaScript.

For more Info Actions

Comment: For the exact scenario you describe, I'd actually create a custom entity with a read plugin.  That way I could call it via REST.  SOAP in JS is just painful.

Answer (score 2):

Actions are really a supported way to create a custom request, that performs a custom action (or more likely, set of actions) and returns a custom response.  I'd say the most likely use case is if you have an external system that needs to perform a set of actions in CRM.  Let's say the external system handles phone calls, and needs to create an account, and a phone call record.  The custom action could accept the phone number and a couple other fields and then generate the Account, Phone Call, and associate the phone call to the account all in one SOAP request.